# The lodow package does not work for downloading the Health and Retirement Study (HRS)

Tags: r, survey

I am trying to download the [Health and Retirement Study databases](https://hrsdata.isr.umich.edu/data-products/public-survey-data) with the `lodown` package. I followed the instructions from this website http://asdfree.com/health-and-retirement-study-hrs.html. However, it is giving me an error. I think it is related to the fact that the databases come in a zip file. See for instance see [h06da.zip](https://hrsdata.isr.umich.edu/data-products/2006-hrs-core). The following error is returned `building catalog for hrs Error in grepl("HarmonizedHRSA\\.zip$", output_filename) :  object 'output_filename' not found` . Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: (1) `lodown` does not appear to be on CRAN, please confirm https://github.com/ajdamico/lodown. (2) This is almost certainly a bug in the package, I suggest you submit a [bug report](https://github.com/ajdamico/lodown/issues/new) based on [this line of code](https://github.com/ajdamico/lodown/blob/773cb1bf8b50c351fdcae790f1bf21ec23af3e41/R/hrs.R#L111), perhaps it should instead reference `this_cat$output_filename`.

Comment: In the meantime to get you started, you can either (1) rewrite `get_catalog_hrs` as a local function and fix the line of code yourself; (2) fork (or at least download) the whole package, fix the line, and `devtools::load_all`; or (3) `debug(get_catalog_hrs)`, run your code, and step-through the function until just before that line, then run `output_filename <- this_cat$output_filename` then `c`ontinue the function (every time you call `get_catalog_hrs`).

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. I don't the package is CRAN yet but it has worked for other datasets like the BRFSS. I tried some of the solutions you proposed, especially (3) but it does not work. It think it has to do with the links. The link in the package do not seem to be correct one. I suspect the website changed their configuration at some point. I have reported the bug and email the author. Hoping get an answer soon. Thank you a lot

Comment: hi @SimRock apologies for the broken code.  the `lodown` package has proven difficult to maintain because authentication and remote filepaths change too often to keep up with  :-/  if you'd like to attempt to fix the error, you're welcome to submit a pull request that edits https://github.com/ajdamico/lodown/blob/master/R/hrs.R however it might be easiest to forgo the download automation in this case